# Words with figurative meaning

Tags: word-usage

There are some words with figurative meaning like *to evaporate* means *to fly away* from the scene. Consider these sentences.

> The Police evaporated from the crime scene without giving any details to the media.

> The personal matters of celebrities are tossed away in public for increasing publicity.

Am I using these words corrects in these sentences?

Comment: Every word can be used figuratively.  There is no way that you can describe figurative use as "correct" or "incorrect"

Comment: There are some figurative uses a native speaker would not use. That's why, when I literally translate an Italian sentence in American, I could not be understood.

Answer (score 1):

*Evaporate* can be used figuratively to mean *disappear, cease to exist*, but usually of something abstract like hope or confidence. It sounds very fanciful to speak of the police evaporating from a crime scene!

*Toss away* usually implies discarding something.

I'm not aware of any list of verbs that can be used in this way; you just have to check all the definitions of each one that you are interested in.